find pump.fun tokens lanched on radium
What method would you use to find all projects/tokens pump.fun has launched? Im trying to understand the logic to even start to put something together. I use python to identify new liquidity pool launches tracking radium wallet but would like to narrow. Any suggestions?

I think a good first step would be to find all tokens launched on pump fun.
Like in solscan you can see all transactions here:
https://solscan.io/account/6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P
So I would parse all transaction, to find the created tokens. And than check these against raydium pools.

The simplest way to identify if a token that just listen on raydium is a Pump.fun token, would be to check the token mint address ends with pump, since this is something all pump.fun transactions does

I wrote this simple script, i hope it helps:
Pump Fun Listener

Here is how to subscribe to events on pump.fun's program:
https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk/blob/main/example/events/index.ts

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Just get Metadata, if it's from Pumpfun there will be a "createdOn" field which has pump.fun as value.
